# How would I insure NO newline in ESLint

Tags: javascript, eslint

From ESLint:

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/eol-last.html

You can disable a check verifying that each file has a newline trailing. However, there does not appear to be an equal/opposite rule. How would I insure that my files have no newline at the end using ESLint? Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the rule [`no-multiple-empty-lines`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines).

```
"no-multiple-empty-lines": [2, {"max": 99999, "maxEOF": 0}]
```

> `max` sets the maximum number of consecutive blank lines.
>
> `maxEOF` can be used to set a different number for the end of file. The
>   last blank lines will then be treated differently. If omitted, the max
>   option is applied everywhere.

Assuming you don't care about the number of empty lines between code, just set `max` to a high number.

Comment: If I wanted to also insure no more than one line between any two lines of code, I could just set max = 1?

Comment: I know this was more than 4 years ago, but for future visitors:
Yes, you can certainly use `"max:" 1` to only allow one blank line between lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Related

1

Below settings for `no empty lines at all`
is `not good`:

```
'no-multiple-empty-lines':['error',{ max:0 }],
```

2

But below `1 line`
looks `better`:

```
'no-multiple-empty-lines':['error',{ max:1 }],
```

For more options:

See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines